# Debug python on linux

Tags: python, pdb

Use pdb to debug python scripts on Linux.

1. When using `import pdb   pdb.set_trace()` to breakpoint. Can I open the tui window like gdb, or a similar code window to see the code in real time?
2. When running to a function, is there a way to let me see where the function is called?

Comment: What Linux distro are you using, maybe this is beyond my knowledge but I use vscode and debugger is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. TUI command for that is `python3 -m pdb script.py` and here is good tutorial on how to use it: https://realpython.com/python-debugging-pdb/

Comment: python3 -m pdb script.py just entered the debugging state. But I want the code to be displayed all the time, and there is an arrow pointing to the current line of execution. Just like gdb tui.